# Websphere 9 isn't publishing WSDL as expected

Tags: web-services, wsdl, websphere, websphere-9

When opening the webservice URL for verifying it's WSDL, the following property is set as:

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="https://localhost:443/HR/services/EmployeeInformation" />
```

But I need it to be set as follows:

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="https://ipw3e.e.corpintra.net:443/HR/services/EmployeeInformation" />
```

If I go to **Application servers > server_name > Installed applications > app_name > Webservices properties > Provide HTTP endpoint URL information**, the URLs are configured as below:
[HTTP endpoint URL information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR1Gm.png)

On the path **Application servers > server_name > Installed applications > app_name > Webservices properties > Publish WSDL files** I can download a zip file that contains de WSDL's correctly configured.

So, the question is: Why Websphere isn't using those WSDL files?

The localhost config comes with the .ear file that development team provides for installing on Websphere. We have another environment running WAS 8 that makes this change automatically and, as far as I know, there is no special configuration made for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to this, 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/uwbs_providehttp.html

there's a jvm prop. you might need to set, com.ibm.ws.webservices.enableHTTPPrefix. Maybe that didn't get carried foward from the 8.x installation.